Tainted dovecot_virtual_delivery issue after exim upgrade
I upgraded my server as Debian Buster -> Bullseyes -> Bookworm, and now exim4 & dovecot won't deliver emails to my mail boxes.
It seems to be related to the following line in /var/log/exim4/mainlog :

R=dovecot T=dovecot_virtual_delivery: Tainted arg 2 for dovecot_virtual_delivery transport command

What's wrong ?

Quoting Kirill Miazine on the Dovecot mailing list :

The just released RC0 for Exim 4.96 will break Dovecot LDA delivery as
described on https://wiki.dovecot.org/LDA/Exim [NB : obsolete link]
Here is the relevant ChangeLog entry:
JH/25 Taint-check exec arguments for transport-initiated external processes.
Previously, tainted values could be used.  This affects "pipe", "lmtp" and
"queryprogram" transport, transport-filter, and ETRN commands.
The ${run} expansion is also affected: in "preexpand" mode no part of
the command line may be tainted, in default mode the executable name
may not be tainted.

Indeed at this time Debian Bookworms uses Exim 4.96.  In their next email, Kirill Miazine suggests, as a workaround, "to create a simple wrapper and call it, instead of dovecot-lda" :
$ cat /local/bin/dovecot-lda-wrapper
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/local/libexec/dovecot/dovecot-lda \
  -d "${LOCAL_PART}@${DOMAIN}" \
  -a "${LOCAL_PART}${LOCAL_PART_SUFFIX}@${DOMAIN}" \
  -r "${LOCAL_PART}${LOCAL_PART_SUFFIX}@${DOMAIN}" \
  -f "${SENDER}"

Then in the dovecot transport file (depends on your configuration, e.g. /etc/exim4/conf.d/transport/20_dovecot) :
dovecot_pipe:
    driver = pipe
## BEFORE
#   command = /usr/local/libexec/dovecot/dovecot-lda \
#                -d $local_part@$domain \
#                -a $local_part$local_part_suffix@$domain \
#                -r $local_part$local_part_suffix@$domain \
#                -r $local_part$local_part_suffix@$domain \
#                -f $return_path
## AFTER
    command = /local/bin/dovecot-lda-wrapper
    […]

(Of course adapt file paths and actual settings to your setup, according to the log message in OP's case it should be dovecot_virtual_delivery instead of dovecot_pipe.)
From what I understand, the trick is that it bypasses Exim strict security checks on arguments because it only sees the script call, leaving the script to handle the internal details.  However the wrapper script encapsulates arguments in shell variables, ensuring they are sanitized and treated as literal strings, so it should still be safe.
